# Run listener when task returns

Tags: java, multithreading, listener, guava, future

I have:

1. An `ExecutorService` that someone else has provided.
2. A `Runnable` task that cleans up after itself when it is interrupted.
3. A `Runnable` listener

My job is to run the task on the `ExecutorService` and then run the listener on the same `ExecutorService` sometime after the task has returned, either normally (via `return`) or by throwing an exception.  I return to my client a `Future` and he (sometimes) calls `cancel(true)`.

My first thought was to use Guava's `ListenableFuture.addListener`... but this executes the listener immediately after the future is cancelled, not after the task returns. However it does have the nice property that the listener is executed immediately if the task completes before the listener is added to the future.  I've included this solution in the SSCCE below.

From the example below, what I **want** is the following:

```
Task Started
Task Canceling
Task Cancelled
**Listener Started**
```

What I **actually** get is:

```
Running
Canceling
**Listener**
Cancelled
```

In this example, I am allowed to change anything inside `myMethod`, the rest is provided to me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Task Started");
                interruptableWork();
                System.out.println("Task Completed");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Task Canceling");
                cleanup();
                System.out.println("Task Cancelled");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

        private void interruptableWork() throws InterruptedException {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        }

        private void cleanup() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable listener = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("**Listener Started**");
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    Future<?> future = myMethod(task, listener, executor);

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }

    future.cancel(true);

}

private static Future<?> myMethod(Runnable task, Runnable listener, ExecutorService executor) {
    ListeningExecutorService listeningExecutor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(executor);
    ListenableFuture<?> future = listeningExecutor.submit(task);
    future.addListener(listener, executor);
    return future;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I'd try is to wrap the task and listener up in a `Runnable`:

```
Runnable wrappedTask = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      task.run();
    } finally {
      try {
        listener.run();
      } catch (RuntimeException e) 
        // log failure?
      }
    }
  }
};
executor.submit(wrappedTask);
```

(Of course, instead of logging listener failures, you could let the failure propagate. I chose to log (a) so that a listener failure doesn't override a task failure and (b) so that a listener failure doesn't override a task success.)